# Is there any XSS threat while having JSON encoded in the URL?

Tags: javascript, json, security, xss, urlencode

In order to have an URL friendly application I'm storing it's context has a JSON in URL, which gives something like :

```
http://mysite.dev/myapppage/target#?context={%22attr1%22%3A{%22target_id-0%22%3A{%22value%22%3A%223%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Hello%22}}}
```

Which encode a basic context :

```
{
"attr1":
    {
    "target_id-0":
        {
        "value": "3",
        "label": "Hello"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm serializing my object with :

```
JSON.stringify(context)
```

I'm deserializing it with :

```
var hashParamsElements = window.location.toString().split('?');
hashParamsElements.shift(); // we just skip the first part of the url
var hashParams = $.deparam(hashParamsElements.join('?'));
var contextString = hashParams.context;
var context = JSON.parse(contextString);
```

The context is only stored to read variables, there's no evaluated code in it. Can someone tell me whether or not it's XSS safe ?

If there's a threat : how can I avoid it ?

Comment: +1 for question. I loved the approach :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A threat of this kind comes from using different methods of decoding JSON, namely `eval` and `new Function`. These execute JS code directly and therefore allow non-persistent XSS attacks by putting code in the url (and linking to it).

`JSON.parse` does not have this issue and is safe against these kind of attacks.

[See also (json.org).](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: Readers should see also @josh3736's answer that is raising an interesting point that could involve potential threats !

Answer (score 2):

Does `label` end up getting inserted into the DOM somewhere?  (IE, `$('#something').html(context.attr1.target_id-0.label)`)

Then I could put `<script>...</script>` in a `label` and there's your XSS.

Comment: +1 Very smart point, I accept @copy's answer which is strictly speaking the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see any threat in it. Its completely safe. `JSON.parse` does not allow any `function` to run.

Also, why using `?` . If you want to give a feel of 'real' url, use hashbang instead.

Comment: I'm using the '?' to avoid all mistakes between this and a real "hashtag"